# Custom taxonomy rewrite in permalinks for posts gives 404 on pages

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, 404-error

So I've got a custom taxonomy (called "version") for just **posts** wich works fine.. My Problem is that i want to use this tax in my permalinks eg `URL.com/12-3/cat/postname`.. which works also fine for the **posts** when i use `/%version%/%category%/%postname%/`for the permalinks.

BUT now every **pages** throws me an 404 error.. (eg URL.com/test -> 404). If i remove `/%version%` it works fine.. but just for the pages.. but i need the version tax in the URL for the posts.. The Code below is used for the tax slugs in the permalinks:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'version_permalink', 10, 3);
function version_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%version%') === FALSE) {
        return $permalink;
    } else {

        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post || 'page' === $post->post_type) return $permalink;

        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'version');
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) {
            $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        } else { $taxonomy_slug = 'no-version'; }

        return str_replace('%version%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
    }
}
```

I guess i made some stupid error i'm not aware of.. When i looked at the var_dump($wp); it shows me eg (for URL.com/impressum):

```
["query_vars"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["version"]=>
    string(9) "impressum"
  }
  ["query_string"]=>
  string(17) "version=impressum"
  ["request"]=>
  string(9) "impressum"
  ["matched_rule"]=>
  string(10) "([^/]+)/?$"
  ["matched_query"]=>
  string(17) "version=impressum"
  ["did_permalink"]=>
  bool(true)
```

so the "**version**" thingy is just registered for **posts** not **pages** but its still looking it up... I've got no clue to solve this, any help or some more insights are much appreciated :-)

fyi the custom taxonomy:

```
add_action('init', 'version_init');
function version_init() {
    if (!is_taxonomy('version')) {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                       => __( 'Versionen'),
            'singular_name'              => __( 'Version'),
            'search_items'               => __( 'Versionen suchen' ),
            'popular_items'              => __( 'Oft genutzte Versionen' ),
            'all_items'                  => __( 'Alle Versionen' ),
            'parent_item'                => null,
            'parent_item_colon'          => null,
            'edit_item'                  => __( 'Version bearbeiten' ),
            'update_item'                => __( 'Version aktualisieren' ),
            'add_new_item'               => __( 'Neue Version hinzufuegen' ),
            'new_item_name'              => __( 'Neue Version hinzufuegen' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Version hinzufuegen oder bearbeiten' ),
            'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Die meistgenutzte Versionen aussuchen' ),
            'not_found'                  => __( 'Keine Versionen gefunden.' ),
            'menu_name'                  => __( 'Versionen' ),
        );
        $rewrite = array(
            'slug'                       => '',
            'with_front'                 => false,
            'hierarchical'               => false,
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'version', 'post',
                          array(
                              'hierarchical' => TRUE,
                              'labels' => $labels,
                              'public' => TRUE,
                              'show_ui' => TRUE,
                              'show_admin_column' => TRUE,
                              'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
                              'query_var' => 'version',
                              'rewrite' => $rewrite
                          )
                         );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your version taxonomy is registered with an empty slug, you need some sort of unique string to prefix those paths.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. well i thought it defaults to $taxonomy, but anyway if i fill it up with some unique string it sadly still doesnt solve this.. 
the "**version**=impressum" from the query, results from the `'query_var' => 'version',` from the register_taxonomy( ... but i dont know why its used on normal pages, ist just a post taxonomy..

Comment: it does default to taxonomy, if you don't supply another value, which you've done. did you flush rewrite rules after making this change? the problem is that a rewrite rule with a higher precedence is capturing those requests, so if you have flushed rewrites, the issue may be that you can't have a non-default query var in the first position of the path. When the first position is a dynamic value, WordPress has to know what it's supposed to be, which it can't guess without looking in the database.

Comment: oh okay, my bad.. and yes I did flush the rewrite rules after making the change.. and again yes it seems its just as you said. When i put it like ´/%postname%/%version%/%category%/´ in the Permalink settings it works.. 
Do you think its possilble to get it still to work with the ´%version%´ in first place??

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got it working now.. I guess its not very clean but it works for me..

First of i fixed the missing `slug` in the `$rewrite` for the `register_taxonomy` but that wasn't really the issue..

1. Since I got (and need) the dynamic value in first place I created a empty dummy parent page for my pages i wanted to show an put them in it. I called it `content`. (Well i could just have altered the permalink manually  but.. i didn't)
2. Now added a new Rewrite Rule to let the pages use the correct query_string

`.`

```
function funny_unicorn_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^content/([^/]*)/?$', // use "content" as prefix to identify my pages
        'index.php?pagename=content%2F$matches[1]', // fix the query string
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init','funny_unicorn_rewrite_rules');
```

In order to make this work I needed to put the parent page back into the string with `content%2F` right in front of the `$matches[1]`

And of naturally i **flushed the rewrite rules** after making the changes..

so the only matter which remains.. it wont work with **WPML**.. when i got a fix for that as well i'll update this post!

cheers